# Error with mock methods

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, mockito

I try to mock some methods in the project so that when they are called, a certain value is returned.
But when you run the tests, they fall with the output:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers! 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
>   -> at com.hodzi.stackviewer.questions.detail.QuestionDetailPresenterTest.voteTest(QuestionDetailPresenterTest.kt:69)
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

If you run the same code in debug mode and run through all the lines, then when you call shared.getToken (), the value that we specified is returned. But with normal startup, tests fall on this line.

Code:

```
import com.hodzi.stackviewer.questions.QuestionsInteractor
import com.hodzi.stackviewer.utils.Shared
import com.hodzi.stackviewer.utils.Vote
import org.junit.BeforeClass
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers
import org.mockito.Mockito


internal class QuestionDetailPresenterTest {
    companion object {
        lateinit var presenter: QuestionDetailPresenter
        lateinit var view: QuestionDetailView

        @BeforeClass @JvmStatic
        fun setUp() {
            val questionsInteractor: QuestionsInteractor =
                Mockito.mock(QuestionsInteractor::class.java)

            val shared: Shared =
                Mockito.mock(Shared::class.java)

            Mockito.`when`(shared.getToken()).thenReturn("23")

//            Mockito.doReturn("23").`when`(shared).getToken()


            view = Mockito.mock(QuestionDetailView::class.java)
            presenter = QuestionDetailPresenter(questionsInteractor, shared)
        }

    }
    @Test
    fun voteTest() {
        presenter.vote(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt(), Vote.QUESTION_DOWN)
        Mockito.verify(view).goToAuth()    
    }

}
```

Shared:

```
interface Shared {
    companion object {
        const val KEY_TOKEN: String = "keyToken"
    }

    fun getToken(): String

    fun saveToken(token: String?)
}
```

Presenter:

```
class QuestionDetailPresenter(val questionsInteractor: QuestionsInteractor, val shared: Shared) :
    BasePresenter<QuestionDetailView>() {
    lateinit var question: Question

    fun vote(id: Int, vote: Vote) {
        print(vote)
        if (Strings.isEmptyString(shared.getToken())) {
            view?.goToAuth()
            return
        }

        val observable: Observable<out Data> = when (vote) {
            Vote.ANSWER_UP     -> {
                questionsInteractor.answerUpVote(id, shared.getToken())
            }
            Vote.ANSWER_DOWN   -> {
                questionsInteractor.answerDownVote(id, shared.getToken())
            }
            Vote.QUESTION_UP   -> {
                questionsInteractor.questionUpVote(id, shared.getToken())
            }
            Vote.QUESTION_DOWN -> {
                questionsInteractor.questionDownVote(id, shared.getToken())
            }
        }
        baseObservableData(observable,
            { data ->
                run {
                    Log.d(Const.LOG_TAG, "success")
                }
            },
            { throwable ->
                run {
                    Log.d(Const.LOG_TAG, "error")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your mocking of `shared`, I think the problem is with:

```
 presenter.vote(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt(), Vote.QUESTION_DOWN)
```

Just use a real `Int` instead of the `ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()`. 
Like

```
presenter.vote(0, Vote.QUESTION_DOWN)
```

Matchers are used when matching arguments on a mocked object, for example

```
val calulator = (mock with Mockito)
when(calculator.divideByTwo(anyInt()).thenReturn(1)
```

would mean `calculator.divideByTwo(int: Int)` returns `1` when called with any `Int`.

When calling methods of real objects to test them (like you do with your presenter), you use real parameters.